# Is stackoverflow using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am a web developer, quite impressed with stackoverflow UI. there are lot of transitions, fade- ins and outs when buttons are clicked.. Is it using jQuery ? could you give me a sample jQuery code ?

Comment: @Raynos if he is a beginner, this is all new to him, your answer is not the most polite...

Answer (score 2):

The source code of this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>    
    <title>javascript - Is stackoverflow using jQuery? - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See that last line? As for sample code, [look here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).